# iOS - dealing with large and growing UIViewController classes

Tags: ios, oop, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that over time has had a lot of delegate events added to it which has made the controller class quite large.  The UIViewController class contains quite a few view-management methods that are called from the event-delegate methods to manage the UIView that the controller is managing.

I am now adding further UIActionSheet delegate events to the class.  My controller class is getting large and I'm thinking that I should break out the UIActionSheet delegate events and place them in a separate delegate class.  This separate delegate class will then have to call back into the view controller class to get the view controller to adjust the view accordingly, using the view-management methods within the view controller. (The view controller accesses a separate model object that the view is representing).

I can see pros and cons to adopting this break-out approach.  It feels wrong to be adding more and more delegate events to the controller, but creating separate classes for different categories of events that then need to call back into the controller also seems to introduce an unnecessary layer of complexity and obfuscation.  The large controller class is 'simple and straightforward' but feels wrong, whilst using numerous different delegate classes will be somewhat more complex and involved but will result in smaller classes.

Can anyone provide some words of wisdom on this topic, and perhaps point me towards some iOS-specific reading on the matter?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created quite a few additional classes for dealing with specific UIActionSheet instances.  I created a base class and then subclassed this for each UIActionSheet requirement within the main controller.

The end result looks tidy, and doesn't add too much complexity.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this matter is:

1. Make it work
2. Make it cleaver
3. Back to 1.
   (Or 1 and 2 both in same turn if you are experienced in a field)

So if code works app looks good but you find that ups some class has 100 methods in it so try different design patters (if you haven`t already) and use those cleaver ideas to make code separation into different classes, delegates, encapsulate them if necessary et.

```
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html
```

Just in case link to Cocoa Design pattern suggestions and i am from time to time looking into `Pro objective c design patterns for ios`. Might be not the best book out there but it is based on "Gang of four" design patterns book in ios context.

Hope this helps at least somehow,

Cheers